What is the relationship between independent variables in Fourier transforms?
$F(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$, and we have a formula for converting between the two, but what is the expression that equates $\xi$ and $x$?
I am doing some image processing simulations. In this case I have some image, a matrix called $I_{in}$, I take the Fourier transform of. Then I have a transfer function with the form
$$ H(\xi,\eta) = \text{sinc}\left[A \frac{\xi}{B}\left(1-\frac{|\xi|}{B} \right) \right]\text{sinc}\left[A \frac{\eta}{B}\left(1-\frac{|\eta|}{B} \right) \right]$$
This comes from $\mathcal{F}\left\{\text{rect}(x) \right\} = \text{sinc}(x)$. So the final Image is $$I_{out} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{H \mathcal{F}\left\{I_{in} \right\} \right\} $$
But my problem is that I need to calculate $H(\xi,\eta)$. $A$ and $B$ are constants based on the geometry. But how do I transform the independent variables from my image space, in $x$ and $y$, to frequency space in $\xi$ and $\eta$?
The function $H(\xi,\eta)$ comes from a paper that doesn't cite the source. My first thought was to compute the inverse Fourier transform of $H$, and maybe the physical relationship between $x$ and $\xi$ would become obvious. But the integral doesn't seem tractable to do by hand and  requires look up tables. Unless anyone has any tips on how to do that.

I don't understand. You give us an expression for $H(\xi,\eta)$ and then you say that you need to calculate $H(\xi,\eta).$

Generally there is no direct relationship between $(x,y)$ and $(\xi,\eta).$ They live in distinct spaces; they are not like Cartesian $(x,y)$ and polar $(r,\theta)$ which are used to parameterize the same space.

I know the expression for H, but in order to calculate the value at each point I need to know the values of $\xi$. And yeah I guess I know there isn't some general relationship, but when dealing with a physical problem, there should be some relationship between the two I would think.

There is no such relationship in physical problems. The Fourier transform of a function of location is a function of linear momentum. There is no relationship between location and linear momentum.

If you are using FFT on an image of size $2^m \times 2^n$ then the transform will have the same size. So you can have $(\xi,\eta) \in {0,\ldots,2^m-1}\times{0,\ldots,2^n-1},$ but probably you want to scale the $\xi$ and $\eta$ (I guess that's what $B$ does.)
